# IOS 8 - After orientation change, Navigation bar is obscured by the status bar

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, orientation, ytplayerview

I'm using SWRevealViewController and my app is locked on portrait orientation. On one of my view controllers I'm launching a youtube player using the `YTPlayerView`. When displaying the video I switch the orientation to landscape programmatically like so:

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

and when exiting the video, back to portrait like so:

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

All works fine, but introduce a layout issue: the Navigation bar Y is not offsetted by the status bar, resulting the status bar to be on top of the Navigation bar (see screens).

**Before orientation change**

[image: Before orientation]

**Playing video on landscape orientation**

[image: Youtube player]

**Navigation bar is being obscured by the status bar**

[image]

What am I missing here :) ?

Comment: Have you solved your problem. I am having the same issue!

Comment: Nop, I have a feeling it's an IOS BUG

Comment: Please, let me know if you find something!

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz . have you solved your issue?

Comment: Yes, I cached the frame size before the move to the video, then restored the frame to the initial position ... kinda of a hack, but it did work

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz Can you clarify a bit more how you solved the issue, I am facing the exact same issue.

Comment: Add a member to your uiviewcontroller:
var navigationFrame:CGRect?
Before playing:
navigationFrame = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame
After exit from full screen
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = navigationFrame!
However, I think this raises other issues ...

Answer (score 0):

Declare a var that will cache initial navigation bar size

```
  var navigationFrame = CGRect()
```

Then, in viewDidLoad save the default value

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
if let navFrame = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame {
      navigationFrame = navFrame
    }
  }
```

After changing orientation call this method to solve to problem:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = navigationFrame
```

This solution is inspired from @Shlomi